# Autocomplete text field firing selection event on load

Tags: codenameone

It looks like the AutoCompleteTextField is firing a suggestion selection event on load. I test this with a ListModel.  You can recreate this issue with the code below from a barebone hello world project.

```
    public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World");

    ListModel<String> suggestionsModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    suggestionsModel.addItem("Apple");
    suggestionsModel.addItem("Banana");
    suggestionsModel.addItem("Chocolate");
    suggestionsModel.addItem("Elk");
    suggestionsModel.addItem("Fish");
    AutoCompleteTextField search = new AutoCompleteTextField(suggestionsModel);

    suggestionsModel.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(int oldSelected, int newSelected) {
            System.out.println("SUGGESTION SELECTED"+suggestionsModel.getSelectedIndex());
        }
    });
    hi.add(search);

    hi.show();
}
```

If you run the code, you can see that the "SUGGESTION SELECTED0" gets printed twice confirming that the selection is firing on load and selecting the first suggestion by default.

This is causing me issues. I am searching for an object and then if found, I am displaying its attributes to the user.  Per this issue, the attributes for the first object is getting displayed by default on load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the behavior of the data change listener which is "over eager", we won't change it as there are some edge cases that depend on this behavior (e.g. paste, instant edit type etc.).

Working with this is pretty easy:

```
if(currentValue != lasValue) {
 ....
}
```